# 100% confidence interval

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

In taking a confidence interval of a sample mean, is it possible to derive a 100% interval? Say a machine produces 200g boxes and infinity samples are taken and the means calculated, would it be possible to state that there is a 100% probability of the population mean lying between these infinite values, or does this violate the assumption that the population mean is unknown?

Comment: Even an infinite sample could be biased

Comment: In this example, the 100% confidence interval must be an interval of infinite length, e. g. $(0; \infty)$.

Comment: so it is possible?